# #1050 - Table 'wp_actionscheduler_actions' already exists

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import an online wordpress website on my local Wamp server. I exported my database from my online website, and now I'm importing it to my local server with phpmyadmin.

Then, the following error message shows up : #1050 - Table 'wp_actionscheduler_actions' already exists

I just created the database, it's definitely empty. Does anyone have an idea to help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get this fixed? I am having the same issue in 2022

Answer (score 2):

*I assume you exported (in quick mode) it to an SQL file in phpMyAdmin. If I remember correctly in the custom mode, there is an option to generate an export file where all the tables have an IF NOT EXISTS suffix*

If this not the case, you can do it manualy:

- Search in your export file for:

`` CREATE TABLE `wp_actionscheduler_actions` ``

- and replace is with

`` CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_actionscheduler_actions` ``

Comment: Thank you, sir, brining attention to the additional options there solves more than one problem, not just for the UI to run the commands, but because they help think what could be going on

Answer (score -1):

Satisfy yourself that you have a good working export of the DB and before running the import routine simply drop the tables.

It should work fine but if not let us know.